# Infinite recursion - predictive parser

Tags: python, parsing, grammar

Well, I have a problem to process this grammar:

```
R -> a R | e
```

e = empty production.

When I try derivate these inputs:
`"a"`, `"aa"`, `"aaa"`.. I get in a infinite recursion.

```
def match(t):
    global pos
    global lookahead
    if lookahead == t:
        try:
            pos += 1
            lookahead = inputstr[pos]
        except IndexError:
            pass
    else:
        raise SyntaxError("syntax error!")

def r():
    if lookahead == 'a':
        match('a') 
        r()
    else:
        pass # e-production

inputstr = raw_input()
lookahead = inputstr[0]
pos = 0
r()
```

I know, the lookahead is not changing, but how can I solve this? I'm beginner in grammars and parsers.

Comment: In short, you keep increasing `pos` despite `IndexError`s that follow once you've run out of input. Among other things required to fix this code, I'd recommend to start with removing any global variables. (Extra credit for not having mutable state at all, except for reading the input.)

Comment: Now it works properly. I can't think in way without global vars.

Comment: @dxhj think arguments and `return` values

Comment: @jonrsharpe Or a `StreamParser` object of some sort...

Comment: May you give some example? ("In short, you keep increasing pos despite IndexErrors that follow once you've run out of input.")

Comment: @dxhj This is pretty obviously an assignment problem and all the comments have given you a lot of clues.  Asking for an example at this point is having someone do the work for you.

Comment: @MyAlias, I just don't understand english very well and the context is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The **pass** inside the IndexError is wrong. Once the input is exhausted,
and every match action was correct, the program should **terminate** with an **OK** status.
However, in your original code, it **does not terminate**,
but keeps reading beyond input buffer and catching its own IndexErrors.
This causes the infinite recursion.
There are three places errors are caught in a predictive parser:

- an incorrect match.
- falling off a switch-case statement in a variable without epsilon rules.
- a return from s() when the input hasn't been read until the end.

To fix this I have added the last if statement.
Altogether the correct predictive parser is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def finish(msg):
    print msg
    sys.exit()

def eat(t):
    global pos
    global lookahead
    if lookahead == t:
        try:
            pos += 1
            lookahead = inputstr[pos]
        except IndexError:
            #pass is wrong here ...
            finish("OK")
    else:
        finish("ERROR")


def r():
    if lookahead == 'a':
        eat('a') 
        r()
    else:
        pass # e-production

inputstr = raw_input()
lookahead = inputstr[0]
pos = 0
r()
##########################
# This needs to be added #
##########################
if pos != len(inputstr):
    finish("ERROR")
```